# SQL query to compare a particular column to the average of the same coloum

Tags: mysql, sql

My Schema is as follows

```
doctor (doctor_name, residence_address, postal_code, year_experience) 
works (doctor_name, branch_name, annual_pay) 
branch (branch_name, branch_address, postal_code) 
patient (patient_name, doctor_name, branch_name)
```

I have been asked to retrieve the **doctor_name** whose annual pay is more than the average of all the doctors in a branch_name called "Singapore"

How do i do that in an sql query. Im using MySQL and so far i have tried this

```
SELECT doctor.doctor_name, doctor.residence_address
FROM doctor INNER JOIN works on doctor.doctor_name = works.doctor_name
WHERE avg(annual_pay)< annual pay
```

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: Could you provide server type (e.g. oracle, ms-sql)?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sorry edited with the proper amendments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT doctor_name
FROM doctor
INNER JOIN works ON doctor.doctor_name = works.doctor_name
WHERE annual_pay > (
        SELECT avg(annual_pay)
        FROM works
        )
    AND branch_name = 'Singapore'
```

Comment: Why select doctors_name from doctor table when it exists in the works table?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution is

```
select doctor_name 
from 
    works,
    (select avg(annual_pay) ap from works where branch_name='Singapore') ap
where
    annual_pay>ap.ap
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare pay with calculated avg from a sub-query

```
SELECT doctor_name, annual_pay
FROM works 
WHERE annual_pay > (SELECT AVG(annual_pay) 
                    FROM works 
                    WHERE branch_name = 'Singapore') 
  AND branch_name = 'Singapore'
```